# User Profile Cleanup - How to do this

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service

Here is the problem, I am only syncing Users from a DomainA. Due to acquisition I now see bunch of users from DomainB in the user profile thus they are showing up in the people search with just their id. For example, DomainB\userID1. I verified in the "Configure Sync Connections" and made sure no other domains are being synced.

How do I remove these unwanted people from user profile db? After this crawl should automatically remove them.

Comment: do both domains have trust? did you put the exclusion filters?

Comment: Yes, both domain have trust. I did not put exclusion filters. Where and how to put the exclusion filters for DomainB? You mean for the search scope?

Comment: Both Domains under one forest or separate forest with trust?

Comment: Different forest with trust.

Comment: I just noticed that all of the unwanted user does not have the PreferredName populated with their name instead it has their user name. How about I exclusion filter for sync connection where PerferredName is null or same as user id. What is the PreferredName in AD? Is it SAMAccountName?

Comment: you are not importing the user from Domain B so you cant exclude them...but these user are not coming from Import process of UPA rather from the Granting the permission directly on sharepoint site.

Comment: Okay. So How do I delete them from User profile? Because I got email from VP that they want to see those users.

Comment: see my answer, two possible way...other than that delete them manually.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure your UPA sync connection only importing users from Domain A but not from Domain B.

As you said Domian B has trust wit domain A, then User from Domain B can access the the SharePoint site without having the profile.

If  user grant permission to domain B user in sharepoint Site, then his incomplete profile will be created as you can see currently. all those user visited the sharepoint sites.

I am sure if you run a Full UPA Sync these profile will be removed.

Or another way is Restrict the People Picker so that no body can see the domain B users in it.
http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/08/30/limiting-people-picker-scope-in-sharepoint/